# How to run database export scripts which SQL Developer is unable to open because of its size

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I exported a database as `sql` from `SQL Developer` now I want to run those exports scripts to import that database.

Issue is that script file is very large around 500 MB .. and SQL Developer is unable to load that files. I even tried using `@scriptFile.sql` syntax but still no use probably this also first open files and than run.

My question is how can I run that file in `SQL Developer`, if I split files into multiple than I don’t want to run each files one by one.

Is there a way I can give it names of all files it can run them all one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird that SQL Developer wasn't able to open files that it itself created.

Anyway I solved this issue by running the script through SQL Plus, size doesn't matter there.

Answer (score 0):

I successfuly run 1.8 GB script file (exported from a table) running the following line from within the worksheet in sql developer (version 4.1.3.20):

```
@"c:\TEMP\scriptfile.SQL"
```